# OSX internet via TimeCapsule - wireless works, wired doesnt

Tags: macos, network-programming, connection

I have a strange problem. My ISP delivers internet over cable. There is a cable modem/router (F-connect in) at the entry-point and from there a wired connection to my TimeCapsule. Everything is fine. I have a OSX laptop and a OSX Mac mini. On both I want to connect to internet via the TimeCapsule. But wired does not work from the Mac mini.

- Laptop: I can get internet-access both by wireless and wired connection with TimeCapsule.
- Mac mini: I can get internet-access by wireless connection with TimeCapsule. But if I make a wired connection to the TimeCapsule it will not get internet access.

Trying to find out why I cant get access when the connection between the Mac mini and the TimeCapsule is wired. AirPort Utility shows green for both TimeCapsule and "Internet". I have tried a lot of things, but I just cant make it work.

Any good ideas on what could possible be wrong on the Mac mini? Any good ideas to "debug" to get more information about what is wrong?

Must say that the Mac mini was recently used as a internet server (mail-server, web-server etc) through the same TimeCapsule but with another ISP and entry-point modem/router. I might have set something up to make that work, but I cannot imagine what I could have set up that create this problem for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• Try giving it a static IP
• Change the cord
• Delete the network then retry
• Plug it into another network

Comment: I tried to use "Assist me..." to create a new "location" (instead of the "Automatic" one which was already there). It tried some automatic thingy, but ended up asking me to enter IP, Subnet Mask, DNS and Router. I did and now it works. I still do not understand why it did not work before, but who cares. Thanks!